Trim not working correctly for different labels and FocusState resets on typing in the TextField
I am making a TextField which, on typing, has a floating label which cuts into the border of the TextField. The trim is not working as expected for different placeholders, for example if the trim works correctly for the placeholder "Name", it does not work for the placeholder "Enter name". Also on the first time you type in the field, the FocusState changes to false. Why is this happening and can someone help with fixing these?
Code for the view:
struct RoundedTextField: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    let placeholder: String
    
    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self._text = text
    }
    
    @State private var width: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var labelWidth: CGFloat = .zero
    
    @FocusState private var isFieldFocused
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(placeholder)
                .foregroundStyle(text.isEmpty ? Color(.placeholderText) : .caribe)
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                .offset(y: text.isEmpty ? 0 : -37)
                .scaleEffect(text.isEmpty ? 1 : 0.8, anchor: .leading)
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .onChange(of: text) { _, _ in
                                labelWidth = proxy.size.width
                            }
                    }
                }
            
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedTextFieldStyle(isFieldFocused: isFieldFocused, textIsEmpty: text.isEmpty, width: width, labelWidth: labelWidth))
                .focused($isFieldFocused)
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .onChange(of: text) { _, _ in
                                width = proxy.size.width * (text.isEmpty ? 1 : 0.8)
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
        .animation(.default, value: text)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct RoundedTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    var isFieldFocused: Bool
    var textIsEmpty: Bool
    var width: CGFloat
    var labelWidth: CGFloat
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding(.vertical)
            .padding(.horizontal, 25)
            .frame(height: 60)
            .if(textIsEmpty) { view in
                view.background {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(isFieldFocused ? .caribe : .gray, lineWidth: isFieldFocused ? 2 : 1)
                }
            }
            .if(!textIsEmpty) { view in
                view.background {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .trim(from: 0, to: 0.55)
                            .stroke(isFieldFocused ? .caribe : .gray, lineWidth: isFieldFocused ? 2 : 1)
                        
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .trim(from: 0.565 + 0.2 * (labelWidth / width), to: 1)
                            .stroke(isFieldFocused ? .caribe : .gray, lineWidth: isFieldFocused ? 2 : 1)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

Conditional modifier:
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self)-> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}


If I understand correctly, the requirement is to create a space in the border for showing the label at a smaller size as soon as any text is entered into the text field.
Using .trim to do this will be difficult. I would suggest, an easier way is simply to apply a background fill to the placeholder text when it moves into position over the border.

This way, no state variables are required for storing the widths of the labels.
This in turn may resolve the issue of the FocusState losing its focused state, because there are less state updates happening.

For this to work, the placeholder needs to be shown as the top layer in the ZStack. So to prevent it from intercepting gestures, you need to apply .allowsHitTesting(false) to it.
You could just apply the background to the placeholder at all times. However, this may cause it to obliterate the blinking cursor, because the placeholder is now the top layer. The animation is also slightly better if the filled background is revealed with a transition effect as the placeholder moves into position.
Other suggestions:

Change the .animation modifier to use value: textField.isEmpty, so that it only applies when the empty state changes.

Always show the smaller label in the placeholder color if the field does not have focus.


Here is the updated example to show it working:
struct RoundedTextField: View {
    let placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    @FocusState private var isFieldFocused

    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self._text = text
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedTextFieldStyle(isFieldFocused: isFieldFocused))
                .focused($isFieldFocused)

            Text(placeholder)
                .foregroundStyle(text.isEmpty || !isFieldFocused ? Color(.placeholderText) : .accentColor)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .background {
                    if !text.isEmpty {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(.background)
                            .transition(.scale)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 17)
                .offset(y: text.isEmpty ? 0 : -37)
                .scaleEffect(text.isEmpty ? 1 : 0.8, anchor: .leading)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
        .animation(.default, value: text.isEmpty)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct RoundedTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    var isFieldFocused: Bool
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding(.vertical)
            .padding(.horizontal, 25)
            .frame(height: 60)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(isFieldFocused ? Color.accentColor : .gray, lineWidth: isFieldFocused ? 2 : 1)
            }
    }
}


